# is this php unique id generator reliable?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, uniqueidentifier, bigint

I'm trying to make a php function that generates unique big int for mysql primary key column .
this is the function :

```
function createUniqueId()
{
     $unique_id="";
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
    {
           $unique_id =  com_create_guid();
    }else
    {
        $unique_id = sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535),         mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
    }
    $unique_id  = str_replace("-","",$unique_id);
    $unique_id  = str_replace("{","",$unique_id);
    $unique_id  = str_replace("}","",$unique_id);
    $unique_id = strtolower($unique_id);
$unique_id = base64_encode(pack("h*",$unique_id));
    $tmp= 1;
for($i = 0;$i<strlen($unique_id);$i++)
{
        $t1 = substr($unique_id,$i,1);

    $tmp = (bcmul((time()*microtime() )^ $tmp ^ ord($t1),2));

}
$unique_id = ($tmp);
    $tmp = "";
    $tm = time();
    $ti = 0;
for($i = 0;$i<strlen($unique_id);$i++)
{
        $t1 = substr($unique_id,$i,1);
        $t2 = substr($tm,$ti,1);
    $val = ord($t1) ^ ord($t2);
    if($val == 0 && $tmp == "")
        continue;
    $tmp .= $val;
    $ti = $ti+1>strlen($tm)-1?0:$ti+1;

}
   $unique_id = ($tmp).(intval(microtime()*10) ^ time()).mt_rand(100,2000); 

$unique_id = strlen($unique_id > 19)?substr($unique_id,0,19):$unique_id;
return $unique_id;
}
```

and this is the test i made( i've tried it alot of times without having any duplicated key but i'm afraid it will someday).

```
for($j = 0;$j<10000 ;$j++)
{
$uid = createUniqueId();//e.g 2329590364151828804 
echo ($j+1)." inserting new record with id = $uid <br>";
//then i add a new line to the table users
echo executeQuery("insert into Users values(?)",$uid,"db_test");
}
```

***UPDATE***

The idea is that i'm trying to get a unique bigint out of the GUID .

Comment: No, if your'e inserting into a DB, then generate and check for it in the DB and generate another if needed.

Comment: @AbraCadaver or by catching exception of duplicated primary key without loosing time checking , right ?

Comment: the guidv4 on its own would suffice.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but i want a bigint for the primary key.
some say it's bad to use string as primary key

Comment: why are you doing all that str_replace, remove the com_create_guid, and just remove the - from the sprintf :/

Comment: You are the primary key

Comment: then why use guid at all lol

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah sure (y)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i want a unique big int  not a varchar ,that is :D

Comment: @Samuel sorry didn't understand.. :/

Comment: What is the reason not to use AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Look within yourself and find the primary key. You are the one.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i don't want the next id to be guessable.

Comment: @Samuel haha that sounds like a riddle xD

Comment: Then why don't you use `random_int()`? (You will need to check for uniqueness either way).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah sure, but i wish to find a solution without checking 
how do you think facebook for example generates the user id ?

Comment: Why not use something like `rand(100000000, 999999999)` and hope for the best? Throw in a little SQL string to check if it already exists: `SELECT id WHERE id = $thisReallyRandomNumber` Then generate a new one if it already exists

Comment: @Samuel in my function i generate a guid that is reliable but i can't make it the primary key i want to get an integer that is unique out of the guid that's what i want i tried to convert the guid to base64 so i reduce the size then tried to do some magic on it (it seems that it works but i cant tell that is reliable)

Comment: @mr.infin8 I am not sure why that'd be... I will try to run your function and see I am able to do that....

Comment: @Samuel thanks for the support (y), I appreciate that

Comment: I get an error when I run your function, bud (`Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered`). This is the line in question `$tmp = (bcmul((time()*microtime() )^ $tmp ^ ord($t1),2));`

Comment: @Samuel wierd i don't get that error. I'm running PHP 5.6.31

Comment: ahhh.. I am on PHP 7 man... No worries... I got you, I can make it happen anyways

Comment: @Samuel alright man (y). Thanks !